# Using Power Bi with too many columns

Tags: powerbi, unpivot

I have an excel sheet with many columns a column cor the count of every car type and expenses for every type as well, for each project per month
when i unpivot the tables it adds too many records
each record has the same total Expenses which dublicates the expenses 5 times

Comment: Have you tried the remove duplicates function?

Comment: Why don't you delete the redundant columns before unpivoting the table? But I guess without either a glass-bowl or a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) no one can really help you.

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to do either of these